# How do you say in a sentence that you have had many accidents and the last one happened last year?

Tags: speech

How do you say in a sentence that you have had many accidents and the last one happened last year?

Does the sentence "*I had an accident only/just last year*"? convey the same meaning?

**Edit:**

I'm not looking for a paraphrase of the sentence "*I have had many accidents and the last one happened last year*". I want to know if there is a common and idiomatic sentence for it. More precisely, I'm looking for a sentence to mean that I'm a careless person who have had many accidents and the one that happened last year is only one of them!

Comment: This question does not appear to be about English language and usage within the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'I have  had/been involved in  a number of accidents, the most recent of which was last year.'

Or if you want to specify one that was not the most recent:
'I have  had/been involved in  a number of accidents, the [verb] of which was last year.'
(The verb being something like 'worst', 'frightening' or even 'exhilarating'.)

If you wish to high-light that you are clumsy/accident-prone, you could add something along the lines of 'Due to my clumsiness, ' to the start of the sentence

e.g. 'Due to my clumsiness, I have had  a number of accidents, the most painful of which was last year.'

or halfway through.

E.g. 'I have been involved in a number of incidents as I am accident-prone, the most embarrassing of which was last year.

'Accident-prone' used to describe someone who tends to have more accidents/mishaps than normal.  http://www.dictionary.com/browse/accident-prone?s=t

Comment: +1 for accident-prone.  Think about how you could re-write your answer to feature accident-prone, which, according to his edit, is what the OP means.   Also, if you decide to do this, give a definition and link for accident-prone.  Dictionary.com has a good, simple definition.